# Is there a PHP-based implementation of Python's Nose?

Tags: php, python, unit-testing, phpunit, nose

I really appreciate Python's [nose utility](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/), which is a testing framework extension that watches your source code for changes and runs the unittests anytime something is modified.

I was wondering whether anything such as this existed for PHP / as a PHPUnit extension? I'm fully aware that this sort of thing wouldn't be difficult to conjure up in bash using watch, but I work across platforms and would ideally like to avoid writing separate implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [watchr](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr) for this.

- [PHPUnit Watchr config](https://github.com/proofek/watchr-phpunit)
- [Another PHPUnit Watchr config](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/14593)
- [Guide on how to combine Watchr, Growl and PHPUnit](http://criticallog.thornet.net/2011/03/08/autotesting-with-watchr-growl-and-phpunit/)

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you. If I could give bonus points, you'd get them for providing the Growl integration article - above and beyond!

Comment: No problem! Just for you information, you can give bonus points by adding a [bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) (you can choose "Reward existing answer" as reason). However, it really isn't necessary in this case ;)

Comment: looks like I can't award a bounty until 24 hours after I've asked the question, but I shall endeavour to be a man of my word :D